# Xamarin Azure AD PublicClientApplicationBuilder GetAccountsAsync returns 0

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to link Xamarin form application (Android at moment) to Azure Active directory and I'm getting an error.  The error comes from the GetAccountsAsync returns 0 accounts and then it can't do any other logic.  The Client Application is created using a Azure AD application that works with my ASP logic.  Can someone please point out what I am missing

**Creating the IPublicClientApplication (PCA) object**
*This is within App.xaml.cs, within the parent project.  The client Id is the client id which works within ASP applications.*

```
      PCA = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientID)
         .WithRedirectUri($"msal{ClientID}://auth")
         .Build();
```

**Below is the Azure redirect setting** 
[image]
**Invoking sign in logic**
*This is what returns the 0 values*
      AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
            IEnumerable accounts = await App.PCA.GetAccountsAsync();

**Error** 
*which does not allow me to go any further*

> {MSAL.Xamarin.Android.4.3.1.0.MsalUiRequiredException: 
>       ErrorCode: user_null
>   Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call.
>     at Microsoft.Identity.Client.AcquireTokenSilentParameterBuilder.Validate () [0x00036] in :0 
>     at Microsoft.Identity.Client.AbstractAcquireTokenParameterBuilder`1[T].ValidateAndCalculateApiId () [0x00000] in <d2976e26cd584ff187181d412fcf7d7b>:0 
>     at Microsoft.Identity.Client.AbstractClientAppBaseAcquireTokenParameterBuilder`1[T].ExecuteAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Microsoft.Identity.Client.AbstractAcquireTokenParameterBuilder`1[T].ExecuteAsync () [0x00006] in :0 
>     at InviteX.Login.OnSignInSignOut (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00149] in D:\InviteX\InviteX\InviteX\InviteX\Login.xaml.cs:33 
>       StatusCode: 0 
>       ResponseBody:
>       Headers: }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [recommended call pattern](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token#recommended-call-pattern-in-public-client-applications):

```
var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();

try
{
    result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
        .ExecuteAsync();
}
catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
{
    result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
          .ExecuteAsync();
 }
```

MSAL will check for accounts in the cache, if there is one, the token will be refreshed behind the scenes and the user will be logged in without being shown a prompt or asked for credentials.

However,  if there is no account, or the refresh token has expired, MSAL will throw a `MsalUiRequiredException`, which you should catch (see above code) and then execute an interactive acquire token call, which will show a prompt and ask the user to enter his/her credentials. Then you will have an account in the cache.